# Node JS Promise Rejection Exception

Tags: node.js

Getting an exception in my Node JS Express application and cannot figure out why. I was getting the same error with my "real" code, so I found this code online and made a test router to see if the error occurred with known good code. Code runs fine in plnkr without the router.post line. Could this be because of the function in the first line? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
router.post('/addTableTest', (function (req, res, next) {
 let promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let data = false;

  if (data) {
    resolve('Data');
  }

  if (!data) {
    reject('Not Data');
  }
})

promise1.then((message) => {
  console.log(message);
}).catch((message) => {
  console.log(message);
})
}));
```

[image: Exception has occurred: string]

Comment: It depends on how a debugger is configured, nothing else. Your environment is unknown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closure executed by `new Promise()` is executed *synchronously*, i.e. immediately after the Promise has been created and *before* `new` returns. As your closure has been written to fail immediately and you can't attach a `.catch()` to it before `new` returns, you get an unhandled Promise rejection exception.

To make your code work you need to

- start a Promise chain by creating a resolved Promise
- attach a `.then()` clause to wrap your synchronous code

  - replace `resolve(X)` with `return X`
  - replace `reject(X)` with `throw new Error(X)`

Now you can safely attach the other Promise clauses, because the code in the just created Promise chain won't be executed until the closure that has created it leaves.

```javascript
router.post('/addTableTest', (req, res, next) => {
    let promise1 = Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => {
             let data = false; // i.e. the promise will reject

             if (data) {
                 return 'Data';
             } else {
                 throw new Error('Not Data');
             }
        });

    promise1
        .then(message => {
            console.log(message);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error.message);
        });
});
```